# How to get C++ code coverage using Bazel?

Tags: c++, code-coverage, bazel

I have a C++ project, and I want to use `bazel coverage` to get its code coverage information.

However, after running the command, I find the file `coverage.dat` inside  `bazel-testlogs` does not contain anything.

So am I looking at the right place? Or is there some problem with Bazel?

I am using Bazel 1.0.0.

Complete Example

`WORKSPACE`

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")

git_repository(
    name = "gtest",
    remote = "https://github.com/google/googletest",
    commit = "3306848f697568aacf4bcca330f6bdd5ce671899",
)
```

`lib/a.cc`

```
int f(int x) {
    if (x == 0)
        return x + 1;
    else
        return 1 + x;
}
```

`lib/BUILD`

```
cc_library(
    name = "a",
    srcs = ["a.cc"],
    visibility = ["//test:__pkg__"],
)
```

`test/my_test.cc`

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(FactorialTest, Negative) {
  EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

`test/BUILD`

```
cc_test(
    name = "my_test",
    srcs = ["my_test.cc"],
    copts = ["-Iexternal/gtest"],
    deps = ["@gtest//:gtest_main", "//lib:a"],
)
```

After I run `bazel coverage //test:my_test`, I see a file at `bazel-testlogs/test/my_test/coverage.dat` generated, but it is empty (0 bytes).

Comment: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/9406
There is already an issue for that exact same problem.
Unfortunately the bazel developers currently do not actively maintain the coverage functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Currently Bazel coverage <> is only support for Linux.

I created a project using bazel for exporting C++ code coverage (https://github.com/hohaidang/STM32-from-scratch/tree/master/004_SPI_driver_CPP)
Open the unit_test folder for more details about BUILD file

Bazel version 3.5.0

`$ bazel coverage unit_test:ut_gpio --combined_report=lcov`

`$ genhtml bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat -o test_coverage`

Note: you should put all test files and source files in the same folder. If different folder it will generate invalid .dat file. I still don't know how to fix yet.

Answer (score 0):

Run `bazel coverage` this way:

```
bazel coverage -s \
    --instrument_test_targets \
    --experimental_cc_coverage \
    --combined_report=lcov \
    --coverage_report_generator=@bazel_tools//tools/test/CoverageOutputGenerator/java/com/google/devtools/coverageoutputgenerator:Main \
    //...
```

Comment: If I just run the command with target `//test:my_test`, I get ```ERROR: output '_coverage/_coverage_report.dat' was not created
ERROR: not all outputs were created or valid
```